# How to configure DBeaver to connect with ms sql server

Tags: server, sql

I am a trainee and in my project i have been working on MS SQL server using microsoft server management studio but now for some reasons i have to use ubuntu for a week or so. I have nothing installed so far on my system.

I have downloaded DBeaver but I do not know how to configure it.
Please give detailed instructions that how should I proceed. What data will I need? I am very very novice in this matter.

About driver configuring and everything.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, we had the same problem. I don't if this will still help you, I just found your question. And to solve my problem, I searched the web as well, but unfortunately, did not find a solution (at least in my quick search). So, what I did to solve it, I was just winging it. Hope you'll be able to reproduce this.

Step 1. Run `dbeaver`

Step 2. Select new connection type, in your case, MS SQL Server -> Microsoft Driver -> Next. [image: Step 2-select new connection]

Step 3. When I did my config, the `JDBC URL`, `Port`, and `Host` were already filled out. So, what you'll be just doing here is to enter your `User name` and `Password` for SQL Server. Then, click `Test Connection`. You'll be prompted to download the drivers, do it. [image: new connection]

Step 4. I did not do anything here. Just click `Next` [image: network-config]

Step 5. I just clicked `Finish` here. [image: final]

Step 6. You're done, you should see the `DBeaver - General` Window. You can now access your SQL Server.
[image: DBeaver]

Comment: What if someone needs to connect via a security-enabled connection string? In my case I get an error message when testing the connection because of the security-enabled connection string.

Comment: I didn't run into such trouble, and didn't explore that config. I'll look into it some other time.